# Using find -mmin to find files with modification time in the future

Tags: linux, find, time

I can use

```
find . -mmin -5
```

to find files changed in last 5 minutes. However, if I try to find files with modification time in the future by giving negative number `find` refuses to do it:

```
find . -mmin --1
```

Is there a way to give future modification time to the standard Linux `find`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To find files modified at least 5 days in the future, use:

```
find . -newermt "5 days"
```

The syntax for the time specification corresponds to the one for `date -d`. See `man find` for info on the switch named `-newerXY` for more information.

It is not possible to use e.g. `-mmin` to do this. It was [reported as a bug against GNU find](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=11667), and was solved by implementing `-newerXY` in findutils 4.3.3 (~2007) as I showed above.

---

Apparently it was not GNU find that was used, but BusyBox.

You should then be able to create a temporary file with `touch -d` and a date in the future and then use the `-newer` switch for `find` such as:

```
touch -d "+5 days" tmpfile
find . -newer tmpfile
```

BusyBox `touch` does not support that date format, but the principle is the same and its `find` supports `-newer`. Creating the reference file with a correct date is left as an exercise for the reader (always convenient to write).

Comment: Thanks. My problem is that my find is old embedded BusyBox find and not binutil find. Apparently standard linux way does not work here. :(

Comment: @Muxecoid: I updated my answer with some BusyBox remarks.

Comment: This just saved me trouble on a new machine where I had done something ten hours in the future by accident (timezone offset applied to an already-offset hardware clock) and after fixing the clock a `configure` script complained about things being in the future (by an hour and a half or so still): `find . -newermt '1 hour' | xargs touch -d '-9 hours'` and I can continue. :-)